# Community Builder platform in Salesforce-Increase space between button and text

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a very simple assignment but for some reason it is not working. I am using the Community Builder feature in Salesforce. All I want to do is increase the spacing between the text and button(the orange marking). See picture below. I have been clicking to the "Page Editor" icon to make changes to the layout. On the side, where it says "Rich Text," I have pressed enter probably a 1000 times to increase the space but the button is in the same position. Can anyone please help on how I can increase the space between button and text?
Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Winter '17, simply pressing enter to create a new line break appears to work as you expect.

For non Winter '17, you could try this:

- Click on the Rich Content Editor (or Rich Text) Lighting Component in the Community Builder
- Click `Source`
- At the very top of the source, you'll see `<p>`, change this to `<p style="padding-bottom: 10px;">`

If you want something like this to happen more than once, you could also create a custom Lighting Component that allows you to pick how much padding you want.